Android displays hint despite of setting contentDescription attribute
For test purpose I am trying to use contentDescription attribute. But for the com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText with the hint set I got this warning:

Do not set both contentDescription and hint: the contentDescription will mask the hint.

And in detailed info:

Note that for text fields, you should not set both the hint and the contentDescription attributes since the hint will never be shown. Just set the hint.

When I set both hint and contentDescription the hint was shown. I tested in API 28 and 34. It looks that android will show the hint anyway, which is what I need. Am I right?
